The selector "app-root" did not match any elements in angular
Good afternoon, everyone!
I'm having a problem with the message "The selector "app-root" did not match any elements." in angular 17.3.5.
I'm migrating from Angular 2 to 17, and I'm creating a study project.
I've had some difficulties involving the use of standalone components. Where I'm using them.
I created a component called Home, where I import my NavBarComponent element.
However, if I search my project, at no point do I use the  selector, but I get this message in the browser console.
Error: NG05104: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG05104
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.mjs:654:13)
    at locateHostElement (core.mjs:11436:34)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:15806:17)
    at _ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.mjs:31460:42)
    at core.mjs:35074:32
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:14882:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at _Zone.run (zone.js:130:43)
    at zone.js:1260:36


The application can be built and uploaded without errors, but I get this exception on any screen of the system
The app-root selector is inside the app.component.ts class
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, HomeComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-consumer';
}


But at no point is it imported into any component I've created, and I don't use it in the project.
the component I'm trying to access is Home.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../navbar/navbar.component';

@Component({
  standalone:  true,
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  imports: [NavbarComponent],
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


In my app.component.html file it is declared as follows
<app-home></app-home>

My classes with @Component are annotated with standalone = true.
Angular's documentation mentions that this may be due to the selector being used, but at no point in my project am I using </.
I tried to solve the problem of opening the component by searching forums

The error message ends with "Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG05104". Have you tried reading that page?

app-root ist User in your index.html and is … well … the root :) please check the file and maybe share it here

I checked my index.html inside the src folder, it's empty, should it have the  inside the index? @ThomasRenger

as I said, I never use this selector, but I did look at the documentation. Thank you for your comment @meriton

Good evening, everyone!
Thanks to @Thomas Renger tip, putting <app-root></app-root> inside index.html solved my problem.
I think it's a directive of Angular itself to make this file mandatory. Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me
